# Combine DataPicker and TimePicker on a Button Flyout in Windows 10 XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-mobile

I'm  making a UWP App (Windows 10). I want to combine the DatePicker and TimePicker in a Button Flyout.
For that, I wrote the following code.

```
<Button Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="ButtonSetAlarmTime">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <Grid Height="100">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="CalendarDatePickerAlarmDate" />
                <TimePicker x:Name="TimePickerAlarmTime" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/alarm-icon.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"></ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

The DatePicker and TimePicker displays as expected. [image]
But the problem is that when I click on any of the pickers, the Flyout closes.

Is there any other way to do this?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Have you managed to fix it?